# Why is __builtin_popcount slower than my own bit counting function?

Tags: c++, gcc

I stumbled on __builtin_popcount for gcc after I had written my own bit count routines.  But when I switched to __builtin_popcount my software actually ran slower.  I'm on Unbutu on an Intel Core i3-4130T CPU @ 2.90GHz.  I built a performance test to see what gives. It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

const int bitCount[256] = {
    0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,  1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,  1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,  2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,
    1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,  2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,
    1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,  2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,
    2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,  4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,
    1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,  2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,
    2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,  4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,
    2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,  3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,  4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,
    3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,  4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,  4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,  5,6,6,7,6,7,7,8
};

const uint32_t m32_0001 = 0x000000ffu;
const uint32_t m32_0010 = 0x0000ff00u;
const uint32_t m32_0100 = 0x00ff0000u;
const uint32_t m32_1000 = 0xff000000u;

inline int countBits(uint32_t bitField)
{
    return
        bitCount[(bitField & m32_0001)      ] +
        bitCount[(bitField & m32_0010) >>  8] +
        bitCount[(bitField & m32_0100) >> 16] +
        bitCount[(bitField & m32_1000) >> 24];
}

inline long long currentTime() {
    struct timeval ct;
    gettimeofday(&ct, NULL);
    return ct.tv_sec * 1000000LL + ct.tv_usec;
}

int main() {
    long long start, delta, sum;

    start = currentTime();
    sum = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
        sum += countBits(i);
    delta = currentTime() - start;
    cout << "countBits         : sum=" << sum << ": time (usec)=" << delta << endl;

    start = currentTime();
    sum = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
        sum += __builtin_popcount(i);
    delta = currentTime() - start;
    cout << "__builtin_popcount: sum=" << sum << ": time (usec)=" << delta << endl;

    start = currentTime();
    sum = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
        int count;
        asm("popcnt %1,%0" : "=r"(count) : "rm"(i) : "cc");
        sum += count;
    }
    delta = currentTime() - start;
    cout << "assembler         : sum=" << sum << ": time (usec)=" << delta << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

At first I ran this with an older compiler:

```
> g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | head -1
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130T CPU @ 2.90GHz
> g++ -O3 popcountTest.cpp
> ./a.out
countBits         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=148506
__builtin_popcount: sum=1314447104: time (usec)=345122
assembler         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=138036
```

As you can see, the table-based countBits is almost as fast as the assembler and far-faster than __builtin_popcount.  Then I tried a newer compiler on a different machine type (same processor -- and I think the mother board's the same too):

```
> g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | head -1
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130T CPU @ 2.90GHz
> g++ -O3 popcountTest.cpp
> ./a.out
countBits         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=164247
__builtin_popcount: sum=1314447104: time (usec)=345167
assembler         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=138028
```

Curiously, the older compiler optimized my countBits function better than the newer compiler, but it still compares favorably with the assembler.  Clearly since the assembler line compiles and runs, my processor supports popcount, but why then is __builtin_popcount more than two times slower?  And how can my own routine possibly compete with the silicon-based popcount?  I'm having the same experience with other routines for finding the first set bit, etc.  My routines are all significantly faster than the GNU "builtin" equivalents.

(BTW, I have no clue how to write assembler. I just found that line on some web page and it miraculously seemed to work.)

Comment: Could be some CPU cache effect. I would not bother

Comment: Try maybe `-march=native`.

Comment: When I have a question about what code gcc is producing, I use -S.  It shows that asm output.

Comment: You should add an example which reproduces the issue, because this is suspicious indeed: "how can my own routine possibly compete with the silicon-based popcount?". Which version of gcc do you use?

Comment: @Mat   `-march=native` did the trick!  __builtin_popcount now has identical speed to the assembler in my example.  I still find it odd that my own routine runs only 20% slower.  popcount must burn a lot of clock cycles.

Comment: @geza I've edited the question to include the pertinent parts of my fastbits.*pp so it's now a stand-alone compilable example.

Comment: @MatthewBusche: On my computer, compiled with clang 6, __builtin_popcount is 3.4x faster than countBits, and asm popcount is 1.3x faster. Which seems OK. The problem with the asm version is that the compiler doesn't unroll the loop, which hurts performance considerably.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without specifying an appropriate "-march" on the command line gcc generates a call to the `__popcountdi2` function rather than the `popcnt` instruction. See: https://godbolt.org/z/z1BihM

POPCNT is supported by Intel since Nehalem and AMD since Barcelona according to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from explaining the difference between the default and `-match=native`, specifically when running the compiler on a recent x86-64 CPU.

Answer (score 6):

I thought it might be useful to share the new performance results after adding -march=native to the compile line (as suggested by Mat and Alan Birtles) which enables use of the popcount machine instruction.  The results are different depending on compiler version.  Here's the older compiler:

```
> g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | head -1
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130T CPU @ 2.90GHz
> g++ -march=native -O3 popcountTest.cpp
> ./a.out
countBits         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=163947
__builtin_popcount: sum=1314447104: time (usec)=138046
assembler         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=138036
```

And here's the newer compiler:

```
> g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | head -1
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130T CPU @ 2.90GHz
> g++ -march=native -O3 popcountTest.cpp
> ./a.out
countBits         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=163133
__builtin_popcount: sum=1314447104: time (usec)=73987
assembler         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=138036
```

Observations:

1. Adding -march=native to the command line of the older g++
   compiler improved the performance of __builtin_popcount to equal
   that of the assembler, and SLOWED my countbits routine by about 15%.
2. Adding -march=native to the command line of the newer g++
   compiler caused the performance of __builtin_popcount to surpass
   that of the assembler.  I presume this has something to do with the
   stack variable I used with the assembler, though I'm not sure.  There
   was no effect on my countBits performance (which as stated in my
   question, was already slower with this newer compiler.)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this and I though it might be able to share more modern and surprising results.

On MacOS 12.2 with Intel i7 7920HQ and when compiling with clang++ 13 using -O3 -march=native the results are following:

```
countBits         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=93142
__builtin_popcount: sum=1314447104: time (usec)=59412
assembler         : sum=1314447104: time (usec)=111535
```

So with modern CPUs and modern compilers it always makes sense using __builtin_popcount.