# How to represent (x ^ y) & 1 in another form?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am trying to find Hamming distance between two integers, and I got it to work with:

```cpp
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
   if((x ^ y) & 1) 
       count++;
   x >>= 1;
   y >>= 1;
}
```

However, it does not work with:

```cpp
if(x & 1 != y & 1)
```

When x = 1 and y = 4, the correct result is 2. However, the second version outputs 1. Sounds like I need a lesson in discrete logic.

How can I rewrite the second if-statement to make it work?

Comment: If you enable all warnings, like`-Wparentheses`,you'll get a message like "warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '&' "`.  You'll save time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `!=` operator has a higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `&` operator, so the condition as written is evaluated as `x & (1 != y) & 1`, but you probably want `(x & 1) != (y & 1)` instead.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I did not know it had a higher precedence than the "&" operator.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the Hamming distance, why not just use [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)?

```cpp
#include <bit>
...
int count = std::popcount(x ^ y);
```

If you can't use C++20 then there is also a compiler intrinsic [`__builtin_popcount`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3849337/1541563) available for GCC and Clang, or `__popcnt` for MSVC:

```cpp
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <intrin.h>
#define __builtin_popcount __popcnt
#endif
...
int count = __builtin_popcount(x ^ y);
```

Comment: Some useful [popcount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52161596/2410359) info.

Comment: Thanks. I also found another way to solve it: return bitset<32>(x^y).count();

Answer (score 1):

This is because bit-wise AND has less precedence than !=

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence