# What's the sense of gcc's `__builtin_popcountll`?

Tags: gcc, built-in

I implemented bitsets (bitmaps) in C.
Assuming that `__builtin_popcountll` is a highly efficient implementation I used that to count bits instead of doing my own implementation.

However when debugging the program it looks as if `__builtin_popcountll` is using some loop (and not what I had expected: Assembly instructions).
Actually when profiling my test program with gprof, `__popcountdi2` consumed 12% of the total CPU, while the "code around" using it took "0%".

So I wonder: What is the use of such builtin when it's seemingly so inefficient?

Platform is x86_64 (AMD EPYC 7401P) using gcc 4.8.5.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52161596/1983398)?

Comment: Well, the performance is an issue, but the question was more about why this function exists as a bullt-in at all. What's the purpose? The other thing is that the question citrd refers to the 32-bit version, while mine refers to the 64-bit version.

Comment: The answer seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161813/6607497

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161813/6607497 the code generated by `__builtin_popcountll` depends on the setting of gcc's option `-march=`*CPU-TYPE*:

- For Intel CPUs the first to support the SSE4a `popcnt` instruction is CPU-TYPE `corei7`
- For AMD CPUs it's CPU-TYPE `amdfam10` or `barcelona`.
- Using CPU-TYPE `native` will also enable it if the current CPU knows the instruction.

When set properly (i.e.: the `popcnt` instruction is known by the CPU), gcc creates corresponding inline assembly instructions;
otherwise it will call `__popcountdi2` (from libgcc2) that counts the bits performing a loop (one iteration per byte).